# Why my custom ruby 'inject' method makes 'self' an empty array instead of the array I'm calling it on?

Tags: ruby, arguments, reduce, self, inject

**So I implemented a custom reduce/inject method as following**

*And I check what's the value of self early on*

```rb
  def my_inject(arg=nil, &block)
    puts self 
    arg.nil? ? memo = self.shift() : memo = arg
    until self.empty?
      memo = block.call(memo, self.shift)
    end
    memo
  end
```

```
   my_array = [3, 5, 8, 9]
   #without arguments works great
   p my_array.my_inject { |m, v| m + v}
   => [3, 5, 8, 9]
   => 25
   #with an argument does not work so great
   p my_array.my_inject(100) { |m, v| m + v }
   => []
   => 100
```

When I call the method on an array I get what I expected only if I don't pass any arguments.

When I pass an argument (here 100) the result of printing self becomes an empty array... and so my 'until' never runs, why is that ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you want to do it idiomatically, you should implement `reduce` on top of `each`. In any case you should _not_ use `shift` - 1st of all this method is defined for `Array` only (unlike `each` defined in `Enumerable`) and, what is even more important, it comes with a side effect (it modifies its receiver)

Comment: Your method empties the receiver. (it literally says `until self.empty?`) That’s why the array is empty when calling it again. It has nothing to do with the argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it helped, I see some of the problems now. Thanks again :)